# Knowing all areas of three overlapping circles excepting the area of $A'∩B'∩C$ and the area of $C$, is it possible to find the area of $A'∩B'∩C$?

Tags: geometry, circles

Let's imagine I have three overlapping circles. I know the following information:

$1.$ the area of circle $A$ = the area of circle $B = 1$

$2.$ the area of $A\cap B =\frac 15$

$3.$ the area of $A\cap C =$ the area of $B\cap C = \frac 9{20}$

$4.$ the area of $A\cap B \cap C=x$ such that $0\lt x\lt \frac 15 $

$5.$ the area of circle $C$ is unknown.

Is it possible, using this information, to find the possible range of areas for $A'\cap B'\cap C$, and thus find the range of areas for $C$?

**EDIT:** I am aware of some methods whereby you can measure [the overlap of three circles](http://www.benfrederickson.com/calculating-the-intersection-of-3-or-more-circles/). I'm beginning to wonder if there's a way to do it in reverse to find $C$.

Comment: What is $A'$ and $B'$?

Comment: A' and B' indicate what is not in A (A') and what is not in B (B'). For example, A' would include all parts of B and C that don't overlap with A, as well as whatever is outside the three circles.

Comment: So you mean the complement? I'm used to the notation $A^C$ and $B^C$.

Comment: Yeah. I just used the notation I'm more used to from when I was in Uni, which is using ' as a way to say "not this."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no upper limit for the area of $C$. The center of $C$ lies on the line $r$ passing through the intersection points of circumferences $A$ and $B$, and the arc of $C$ inside $A$ approaches a straight line when the radius of $C$ tends to infinity. That limiting line is perpendicular to $r$ and cuts $A$ so that the lesser part is 45% of $A$. This situation is compatible with your constraints because $\hbox{area}(A\cap B\cap C)=0.45\ \hbox{area}(A\cap B)=0.09$.

A lower limit can be found, because it corresponds to the situation when the three circumferences have a point in common. Again, the bound on the area of $A\cap B\cap C$ is unimportant, but the area of $A\cap C$ is $0.45$ and this implies the radius of $C$ cannot be too small. Experimentally the lowest area turns out to be around $0.72$.

Comment: I've checked my final result with GeoGebra and I confirm it is around $0.72$, which is different from that given by Hagen. It's possible that I made an error somewhere, but I'd suggest @Hagen to check his value of $C$.

Answer (score 1):

From 1 and 2, the circles $A$ and $B$ are completely determined (up to movement of the whole figure). Indeed, on finds radius $$r=\sqrt{1/\pi}\approx 0.56418958354775628694807945156077258585$$ and numerically using [suitable formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html) a distance of circle centres $O_A$, $O_B$ of $$d\approx 0.77525158218538574803265479010075364915.$$

From 3 we know that the centres of the circle form an isosceles triangle.
If we assign coordinates $O_A=(-\tfrac d2,0)$, $O_B=(\tfrac d2,0)$, we may assume that $O_C=(0,y)$ for suitable $y>0$. 
Note that $A$ and $B$ intersect in $(0,\pm h)$ with $$h=\sqrt{r^2-\frac14d^2}\approx 0.40994649926978848797914142299189026942.$$
From 4 we infer that the radius $r_C$ obeys $y-h<r_C<y+h$.
We can solve numerically, for which $y$ the lens-shaped area of $A$ intersect the circle around $(0,y)$ with radius $y+h$ equals $0.45$ and find
that this happens at
$$\tag1 y=y_0\approx 0.24774217358345628137394294376637568202.$$ 
We should do the same (for $y>h$)with radius $y-h$ in place of $y+h$ to investigate the other end. However, the resulting lens-shape will always be less than the circle segment determined by the horizontal line through $(0,h)$, which is less than $0.45$ in area.
We conclude that the only restriction comes from $(1)$, i.e., 
$y$ may take any value $>y_0$ and can otherwise grow arbitrarily large. At the same time, the radius $r_C$ can vary from $y_0+h$ up to infinity.
In other words, all that can be said about $C$ is that 
$$ C>\pi(y_0+h)^2\approx 1.3589096951569625386674237564989042025.$$

Comment: Hm... interesting. So we can only find the lower limit of C given what information is present? Kind of a bummer.